# insert NULL value in sybase database using python

Tags: python, sql, django, null

Let's say we have the following sql statement:

```
INSERT INTO myTable VALUES (1,"test")
```

In my python code the first value is either an integer or NULL. How can I insert `NULL` value using python code?

Code snippet:

```
    var1 = getFirstValue()
    var2 = getSecondValue()
    qry = "INSERT INTO myTable VALUES (%d,%s)" % (var1,var2)
```

Whenever var1 is None it is throwing error, but I want NULL to be inserted.

Comment: Since you tagged the question with Django, why do you need to insert anything into db manually? Just use Django ORM.

Comment: I'm new to django, can you point me to some kind of tutorial where I can get thorough understanding of django ORM

Comment: follow the link in @Bogdan Barbieru answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
qry = "INSERT INTO myTable VALUES ({0}, {1})".format(var1, var2)
```

Comment: From your question it is not clear which database you are using, so I just added a general way. Even you didn't added the error too. You should explain your question more. So I added an answer like your question. For this atleast when you execute only these 3 line and var1 = None, it will not throw error.

Comment: Assuming `var1 = 123 and var2 = None` (equivalent of null), this would return: `INSERT INTO myTable VALUES (123, None)`  'None' will cause it to error out

Comment: @Nicarus Why the downvote and why you are assuming var2 will be None when in his question it is clearly written he want var1 = None

Comment: He doesn't want to *pass* None into the query - he wants to pass it in as NULL

Answer (score 1):

Since you marked this question with the tag Django, you must be aware that you don't just write queries and save them in the Database, Django handles this.

Just check the Tutorial that is available here : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/intro/tutorial01/

Since you mentioned Sybase, you must get the Django driver from (https://github.com/sqlanywhere/sqlany-django) and modify the DATABASES entry inside your settings.py project. (first finish the tutorial)

Answer (score -1):

Here is one possible option:

```
var1 = getFirstValue()
var2 = getSecondValue()

var2 = "'{0}'".format(var2) if var2 is not None else 'NULL'

qry = "INSERT INTO myTable VALUES ({0},{1})".format(var1,var2)
```

Comment: I assume & I am pretty sure he do not want to enter string 'NULL'. He wants to enter the value of NULL.

Comment: This will enter NULL and not 'NULL'. Run it for yourself and test it

Comment: Yes it enters NULL and not 'NULL'. Thanks Nicarus.